# How to retrieve all images that have a certain tag in Laravel with Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables:

```
Table: images
Columns: Image_ID, Title, Description, Author, Date, Path, Rating

Table: tags
Columns: Tag_ID, Title

Table: tag_image
Columns: Image_ID, Tag_ID
```

If I wanted to get all images, I'd do this:

```
public function specificTag($tagName){
        $images = Image::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        return view('specificTag', ['images' => $images]);
    }
```

and then loop through $images in my specificTag view. However, now I only want to display only the images which have $tagName tag. $tagName is a string. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use the `whereHas` method.

```
Image::whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($tagName) {
    return $q->where('title', $tagName);
})->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, where do I define the variable $images?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you take advantage of Eloquent's Many to Many RelationShip.
Create the following function in your "Image" Model.

```
public function tags(){
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tags');
}
```

Now in your controller you can access it like this

```
$image = App\Image::find(1);
foreach($image->tags as $tag){
   $tag->where('title',$title);
}
```

You may have a look on Eloquent's Relationship https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many